# Advice on sending JSON to Function App via Synapse (iteratively)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-synapse

Can anyone help with advice on calling a Function App from Synapse? I'll provide some background below.

- we have some transformed JSON files in ADLS which we need to send as the body of the Function App call, these need to be sent iteratively one file at a time.
- we've tried calling the Function App from a Synapse Spark Notebook and a Pipeline both of which took too long and cost too much for us.
- In the Pipeline we did a Lookup to get data per file and sent the output through to a Function App activity.
- In the Notebook we used POST to send through the JSON payload.
- the output from the Function App call is saved in ADLS, with one file per iteration of the loop.

Any advice on best practice would be great!

Comment: Why are using Lookup here, are you sending lookup output to function app?

Comment: Yeah, we're using the output from the Lookup to grab the JSON data and send it through to the Function App body.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems right. Make sure to use string interpolation while calling the lookup activity output: `@{activity('lookup').output.value}`

Additionally, ensure correct headers are used in the azure function activity
For better performance , try to optimize the function app code.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you need to pass each file's lookup output as body to the function app. In this case, you can run the iterations parallelly instead of sequential.

Go to the For-Each activity and uncheck the **Sequential** checkbox here.

[image]

This will run a maximum of 50 iterations at a time parallelly and next 50 parallelly etc. This reduces the time taken for the pipeline run. But note that, you should not any activities that needs the sequential runs like incrementing any numbers or dependencies on previous runs. Only in these cases, it will work.

Also, you can try logic app to achieve your requirement.

- Use the **List blobs** action to list the files inside the folder. Create a storage account connection and Give the path till the folder here. This will give list of all file paths.
- Next, use a for-loop and give the above array output `@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']` to this. Inside loop, use `Get_blob_content_(V2)` by path and give the `@items('For_each')?['Path']` as path.
- After that to get the JSON array, use `Compose` with `json(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))` expression.
- Then, [`call your function app from logic app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption) in every iteration. Pass the output array from **Compose** to this.

**Sample logic app flow:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. We're also trying this via a Logic App but for our approach we need to use Synapse Notebooks or Pipelines. For comparison the Logic App takes milliseconds for each Function App call. 
We've tried running the loop sequentially (for testing one or two files) and each call to the Function App takes 1.5-2 mins. When we try up to 50 in parallel each call takes ~17mins and we tried up to 4 in parallel and cancelled this after around ~5 mins per call.

Comment: The parallel should take less time than sequential. If still its results same, then optimizing the function app code might be the only workaround here to reduce the time.